# Angular 17 stuck on Changes detected. Rebuilding

Tags: angular, angular17

I'm using Angular 17 with these configurations in my package.json

```
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "17.1.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.1.2",
```

After I change a file it only reloads the page for the first time and on second time it gets stuck on `Changes detected. Rebuilding...` and nothing happens.

And when i use ng serve --verbose I see that it detects the file that is being modified but it doesn't rebuild the project:

```
  "added": [],
  "modified": [
    "/Users/goldenfox/Projects/front/src/app/pages/public/about/about.component.ts"
  ],
  "removed": []
⠦ Changes detected. Rebuilding...
```

Any idea how to fix this? After updating to Angular 17 I need to stop ng serve and run it again after every change.

Comment: Node is up to date? Which builder are you using? There are some issues with esbuilder. I face some other issues with the builder too, but not that hard

Comment: @ThomasRenger Thanks for your comment. Node is 20.11 and I'm using `@angular-devkit/build-angular:application` for build and `@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server` for serving

Comment: I"m facing the same problem. I couldn't fully migrate angular 16 to angular 17 because of strange dev server issues. It would hang on initial load, page keeps spinning, and no errors logged, and out of memory issues. Doesn't feel stable

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, after a long search i found that for some reason i was checking if it was in a productionmode to call enableProdMode() in main.server.ts and in main.ts.

When i removed it did rebuild and reload on changes in files again.

```
//if (environment.production) {
//  enableProdMode();
//}
```

For some reason i was also importing zone.js into main.server.ts. I tried several things and sometimes it did only worked when i removed this import statement.

Comment: if you are using ng serve -c --production then that condition is false and it doesn't matter if its commented or not.
The issue is not related to that it just sometimes fixes and happen again after some more changes and you think its fixed.

Comment: @BehnamAminazad I think it also has more to do with the if statement, it resolved my problem of getting stuck on 'Changes detected. Rebuilding...' anyways. And i was able to reproduce it when uncommenting this code.